# AsEnumerable and AsQueryable

Tags: linq-to-entities

```
var test1 = DB.UnAuthPriorityLevelTypes.AsEnumerable();
var test2 = DB.UnAuthPriorityLevelTypes.AsQueryable();
var test3 = DB.UnAuthPriorityLevelTypes.ToList();
var test4 = DB.UnAuthPriorityLevelTypes.AsEnumerable();
var test5 = DB.UnAuthPriorityLevelTypes.AsQueryable();
```

In the above five statements, if I look at the count of values in `test1` and `test2` it's 0, but `test3`, `test4`, `test5` have the count value of 3, which was supposed to be the case. Why?

Update:

Even though test1 shows as 0 results , i m able to loop through it successfully and get the values
I thought the problem is due to Lazy Loading behaviour of EF but i tried to disable it and ran it but no go

```
 if(DB.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled)
                DB.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: What kind of database is this ? How did you look at 'count of values' ?

Comment: This is SQL server Database. I m seeing the count while doing the debugging. And as I stated, while doing the iteration through that Ienumerable variable, I could successfully loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of deferred execution of Linq, you should read `AsEnumerable` and `AsQueryable` as a declaration for the query to execute.

Once you run `ToList` you enforce an execution of the query and the datacontext will contain all the rows from `DB.UnAuthPriorityLevelTypes` and therefore Count will show the correct number and this will not change as long as the context is not disposed.

`LazyLoadingEnabled` flag influences related related rows, see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I assumed setting the LazyLoading flag will change the deferred execution.

Comment: It changes it for the navigation properties.